# I am unable to install Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, epel

I am unable to install Apache 2.4. Like I got this error:
**Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again.**

I update ca-certificates packages and also do commenting mirror list and un-commenting base url's, but at the end got the package of 2.2. Kindly help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Apache 2.2 totally, then do install Apache 2.4.

Comment: I did it, but when run the command  yum install httpd, got the below result
httpd 2.2